# im accessing two files in the same location for compiling but the first is getting read and the second one throwing an [Errno 22] Invalid argument

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

The whole code is below in my previous laptop it used to work since i changed my laptop im getting  OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument:

```
#Combine both allocation sheets from shared drive
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date
import xgboost as xgb

print("Reading Both Files")

New= pd.read_excel(r"Z:\OA\Reena\COPY OF BI REPOSITORY\ALLOCATION\NEW 
ALLOCATION Sheet 2018.xlsx",sheet_name="based on AC DC post 2019")
Old= pd.read_excel(r"Z:\OA\Reena\COPY OF BI REPOSITORY\ALLOCATION\ALL 
OLD ACCOUNTS.xlsx",sheet_name="Based of acntDC til2018")



print("Reading Both Files Completed")

Allocation = [New,Old]



Allocation = pd.concat(Allocation)



Allocation['Alexa Rank - Global'].fillna('N/A', inplace=True)
Allocation['Alexa Country Rank'].fillna('N/A', inplace=True)
Allocation['Publisher'].fillna('NA', inplace=True)

                                        
Allocation.to_excel("Allocation_Dump.xlsx",index = False)

print("Allocation_Dump good to use")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add more info on this:

- what does the rest of the code look like
- Have you tried switching the files with each other
- Are there any other processes locking one of the files (Excel for example)
- Is a third excel file being read
- etc etc

You need to give us more to help you.